# Trying to see if two Polynomials are the same (sameness)

Tags: java, assertion

I am trying to make a class (and a few subclasses and interfaces) to represent a Polynomial. First I have a monomial class which has fields for a coefficient and degree of a Monomial.

```
public class Monomial {

  int coef;
  int degree;

  public Monomial(int coef) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    super();
    this.degree = 1;
    this.coef = coef;

  }

  public Monomial(int degree, int coef) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (this.degree < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("non positive degree");
    }
    this.coef = coef;
    this.degree = degree;

  }

  public int getDegree() {
    return this.degree;
  }

  public int getCoef() {
    return this.coef;
  }

  public boolean sameMonomial(Monomial that) {
    return this.coef == that.getCoef()
            && this.degree == that.getDegree();
  }



}
```

Next, I have two classes, which implement an interface called ILoMonomial. The ILo stands for (Interface List-of) and it used to represent a list of Monomials.
Therefore, the class MtLoMonomial is an empty list and the base case of the list, having no fields. The ConsLoMonomial class has two fields, a Monomial as the (first) item in the list, and An ILoMonomial as the (rest of the list).

```
public interface ILoMonomial {

  boolean findAnyDupes();
  boolean findAnyDupesHelper(int degree);

  boolean findSameHelper(Monomial that);

  boolean findSame(ILoMonomial that);

}
```

```
public class MtLoMonomial implements ILoMonomial {

  MtLoMonomial(){}

  @Override
  public boolean findAnyDupes() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean findAnyDupesHelper(int degree) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean findSameHelper(Monomial that) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean findSame(ILoMonomial that) {
    return false;
  }

}


public class ConsLoMonomial implements ILoMonomial {

  Monomial first;
  ILoMonomial rest;


  ConsLoMonomial(Monomial first, ILoMonomial rest) {
    this.first = first;
    this.rest = rest;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean findAnyDupes() {
    return this.rest.findAnyDupesHelper(this.first.getDegree()) &&
            this.rest.findAnyDupes();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean findAnyDupesHelper(int degree) {
    return degree == this.first.degree;
  }


  public boolean findSameHelper(Monomial that) {
    return that.sameMonomial(this.first);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean findSame(ILoMonomial that) {
    if (that.findSameHelper(this.first)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return that.findSame(this.rest);
    }

  }



}
```

Finally, I have my Polynomial class, which is where I am running into trouble on how to go about implementing the samePolynomial class. In this class, the only field I have is the ILoMonomial.
I have no idea how to go about this. I have a few helper methods in the classes which implement ILoMonomial (findSame, and findSameHelper)
(but as of now only findSameHelper works and possibly only for the first item in the list).

Here is some example code

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
public class ExamplesPolynomial {

  Monomial oneRaisedToFourth = new Monomial(1, 4);
  Monomial twoRaisedToOne = new Monomial(2, 1);
  Monomial twoSquared = new Monomial(2 , 2);
  Monomial threeXSquared = new Monomial(3, 2);
  Monomial five = new Monomial(5, 1);
  Monomial coefOf2 = new Monomial(2);

  ILoMonomial threeXSquaredPlusFive = new ConsLoMonomial(
          threeXSquared, new ConsLoMonomial(
                  five, new MtLoMonomial()));

  ILoMonomial ListOfMonomial1 = new ConsLoMonomial(oneRaisedToFourth,
          new MtLoMonomial());
  ILoMonomial duplicateDegree = new ConsLoMonomial(twoRaisedToOne,
          new ConsLoMonomial(coefOf2, new MtLoMonomial()));
  ILoMonomial threeXSquaredPlusFive_Reversed = new ConsLoMonomial(five,
          new ConsLoMonomial(threeXSquared, new MtLoMonomial()));


  Polynomial error = new Polynomial(duplicateDegree);
  Polynomial fine = new Polynomial(threeXSquaredPlusFive);

  // passes
  @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void testPolynomial(){
    Polynomial error = new Polynomial(duplicateDegree);
  }

  // passes
  @Test
  public void testPolynomialTrue() {
    Polynomial noError = new Polynomial(new ConsLoMonomial(threeXSquared,
    new ConsLoMonomial(twoRaisedToOne, new MtLoMonomial())));
  }

  // passes
  @Test
  public void testSameMonomial() {
    assertTrue(coefOf2.sameMonomial(coefOf2));
    assertFalse(coefOf2.sameMonomial(threeXSquared));
  }

  // passes
  @Test
  public void testFindSameHelper() {
    assertTrue(ListOfMonomial1.findSameHelper(oneRaisedToFourth));
    assertFalse(ListOfMonomial1.findSameHelper(threeXSquared));
  }

  // fails : assertion error 
  @Test
  public void testFindSame() {
    assertTrue(threeXSquaredPlusFive.findSameHelper(five));
  }

  // fails : assertion error
  @Test
  public void testSamePolynomial() {
    Polynomial reverse = new Polynomial(threeXSquaredPlusFive_Reversed);
    Polynomial normal = new Polynomial(threeXSquaredPlusFive);
    assertTrue(reverse.samePolynomial(normal));
  }


}
```

Comment: I would recommend redesigning / rethinking the problem. For starters, consider having a `public class Polynomial`. I suggest it has a `private` instance variable that is either an array of coefficients or some type of `Collection` of your `Monomial`.

Comment: Suppose a user of your code wants to enter terms that have the same degree?  For example, **2x^2 + 7x + 8x^2 + 14** ?